# Naming LDA topics in Python

Tags: python, label, lda

I am new to python and trying to implement topic modelling. I am successful in implementing LDA in pything using gensim , but I am not able to give any label/name to these topics. 
How do we name these topics? please help out with the best way to implement in python. 
My LDA output is somewhat like this(please let me know if you need the code) :-

0.024*research + 0.021*students + 0.019*conference + 0.019*chi + 0.017*field + 0.014*work + 0.013*student + 0.013*hci + 0.013*group + 0.013*researchers
0.047*research + 0.034*students + 0.020*ustars + 0.018*underrepresented + 0.017*participants + 0.012*researchers + 0.012*mathematics + 0.012*graduate + 0.012*mathematical + 0.012*conference
0.027*students + 0.026*research + 0.018*conference + 0.017*field + 0.015*new + 0.014*participants + 0.013*chi + 0.012*robotics + 0.010*researchers + 0.010*student
0.023*students + 0.019*robotics + 0.018*conference + 0.017*international + 0.016*interact + 0.016*new + 0.016*ph.d. + 0.016*meet + 0.016*ieee + 0.015*u.s.
0.033*research + 0.030*flow + 0.028*field + 0.023*visualization + 0.020*challenges + 0.017*students + 0.015*project + 0.013*shape + 0.013*visual + 0.012*data
0.044*research + 0.020*mathematics + 0.017*program + 0.014*june + 0.014*conference + 0.014*- + 0.013*mathematicians + 0.013*conferences + 0.011*field + 0.011*mrc
0.023*research + 0.021*students + 0.015*field + 0.014*hovering + 0.014*mechanisms + 0.014*dpiv + 0.013*aerodynamic + 0.012*unsteady + 0.012*conference + 0.012*hummingbirds
0.031*research + 0.018*mathematics + 0.016*program + 0.014*flow + 0.014*mathematicians + 0.012*conferences + 0.011*field + 0.011*june + 0.010*visualization + 0.010*communities
0.028*students + 0.028*research + 0.018*ustars + 0.018*mathematics + 0.015*underrepresented + 0.010*program + 0.010*encouraging + 0.010*'', + 0.010*participants + 0.010*conference
0.049*research + 0.021*conference + 0.021*program + 0.020*mathematics + 0.014*mathematicians + 0.013*field + 0.013*- + 0.011*conferences + 0.010*areas

Answer (score 0):

*Labeling* topics is completely distinct from topic modeling. Here's an article that describes using a keyword extraction technique (KERA) to apply meaningful labels to topics: http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2359